# Measurement outcomes of a "not totally decohered" system

Tags: decoherence, foundations

In decoherence theory, the basic situation is the following (I illustrate with two level system for simplicity). I want to measure a system $S$ by the mean of an apparatus $A$. Around it there is the environment $E$. The initial state of the apparatus is $|0\rangle$, the initial state of the environment is $|E_0\rangle$.

I assume the system is initially in $|\psi_S \rangle = a |0 \rangle + b |1\rangle$, the environment is initially in $|E_0(t) \rangle$. I want to measure the observable $\sigma_z$.

The first step if the pre-measurement: system and apparatus get quantum correlated:

$$|\psi_S \rangle |0\rangle |E_0\rangle \rightarrow \left( a|00\rangle + b|11\rangle \right) |E_0\rangle $$

The second step is the correlation with the environment:

$$\left( a|00\rangle + b|11\rangle \right) |E_0\rangle \rightarrow a|00E_0(t)\rangle + b|11E_1(t)\rangle$$

Tracing out the environment, we have, with $r(t)=\langle E_1(t) | E_0(t) \rangle$

$$\rho_{SA}=|a|^2 |00\rangle \langle 00| + |b|^2 |11 \rangle \langle 11 | +ab^* r(t) |00\rangle \langle 1 1| + a^*b r^*(t) |11\rangle \langle 00 |$$

The system fully decohered will be obtained for $r(t)=0$ (if I wait long enough in practice).

**My question is:**

What will I see on my apparatus before the environment has completly killed the coherence (if I look "fast enough"). My apparatus is supposed to tell me if my system is in $0$ or in $1$. And without all the coherences being killed I am struggling to understand what it would tell me.